# VSPackage: How to get selected file when there is no "real" solution opened

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vs-extensibility, vspackage

I'm developing a **VSPackage** in C#, and I would like to know how to get the current file, when only a single file (or several files are opened in Visual Studio).

All works fine when there is a hierarchy (a *real* solution opened). But when I open a single file in Visual Studio, I cannot get the curren selection. I mean open Visual Studio (without solution) and `select File` -> `Open` -> `File`.

I need to get one of these: itemid, documentCookie, mkDocumentName or whatever.

I tried the following:

- `IVsMonitorSelection.GetCurrentSelection()` -> It always retrieve the solution item id without hierarchy (Intpr.Zero)
- `IVsSelectionEvents` -> I tried to listen the selection event, the new itemId is always the solution itemid
- `RunningDocumentTable` -> Well, I'm close to find the solution, because I can enumerate the opened files, but I'm not sure how to determine which is the current one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like something that the DTE can solve for you. Have you checked DTE2.ActiveDocument (retrieved by querying for SDTE)?

```
var dte = (DTE2)GetService(typeof(SDTE));
var doc = dte.ActiveDocument;
// Check doc.Name, doc.Path, doc.FullName
```